# Issue parsing XML when com.fasterxml.aalto-xml is in the Maven dependency

Tags: java, xml, maven, fasterxml

I'm having trouble with the library com.fasterxml.aalto-xml.

I Have a Project A (Dspace) that do not depend on the library com.fasterxml.aalto-xml.

I developed a library B, that use a library C that depends on com.fasterxml.aalto-xml.

> I wonder why when [com.fasterxml.aalto-xml](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml%7Caalto-xml%7C0.9.7%7Cbundle) gets added as a
>   dependency to A by way of B -> C, A picks up
>   [com.fasterxml.aalto-xml](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml%7Caalto-xml%7C0.9.7%7Cbundle) to do his usual XML Parsing.

The problem is that, it breaks the application. [com.fasterxml.aalto-xml](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml%7Caalto-xml%7C0.9.7%7Cbundle) is having trouble to properly parse the XML that comes originally with A. Something is going wrong.

I would like to understand why does it happens. Is there a way to tell A not to use [com.fasterxml.aalto-xml](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml%7Caalto-xml%7C0.9.7%7Cbundle) but still having B -> C -> [com.fasterxml.aalto-xml](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml%7Caalto-xml%7C0.9.7%7Cbundle) at work within the A project.

What is particular about those XML parsers? I just don't understand why A would pick up com.fasterxml.aalto-xml to work with it, while it does not have any dependency on it.

I can see that the lib is also an osgi bundle jar, may it has any implication here ?

> I mean originally A (Dspace) works without alto and use whatever
>   parser it has, why picking alto now that it is in the dependency ? what mechanism allow that ?

Answer (score 1):

`com.fasterxml:aalto-xml` contains an implementation of the StAX API. That API (which is part of the JRE starting with Java 6) uses the service provider discovery mechanism described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) to locate implementations. Therefore, by simply adding the Aalto JAR to the classpath, you change the implementation that is used by the StAX API. All libraries that use the StAX API (A and C in your case) will be equally affected by that.